# C existing pointer to fixed-size array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say that any C function has a pointer already declared, but not assigned any value yet. We will int for our examples.

```
int *ptr;
```

The goal of the function is not to assign `ptr` any dynamic memory on the heap, so no `malloc` call. Instead, we want to have it point to an array of fixed size `n`. I know I could accomplish this like so:

```
int arr[n];
ptr = arr;
```

However, the code could get very messy and hard to read if we need to do this many times in a function, ie, a struct of many pointer fields all need to point to an array of fixed length. Is there a better way to accomplish this in one line? I was thinking of something similar to below, but it looks too ambiguous and uncompilable:

```
int *ptr;
// Many other things happen in between...
ptr[n];
```

*****EDIT*****
Here, the below additional information may help guide some more answers (not saying that the current answers are not fine). In my use case, the pointers are declared in a struct and, in a function, I am assigning the pointers to an array. I want to know if there is a simpler way to accomplish this than in the below code (all pointers to point to fixed-length array):

```
struct foo {
    int* a;
    short* b;
    char* c;
    ...
};

void func(void) {
    struct foo f;
    int n = ...;
    int tempArr1[n];
    f.a = tempArr1;
    short tempArr2[n];
    f.b = tempArr2;
    char tempArr3[n];
    f.c = tempArr3;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is more than ambiguous -- it will / can cause a memory fault if the memory has not been allocated at run-time or compile time.

Comment: Why do you need `ptr`? Why not just use `arr` directly?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - he does not like how it looks.

Comment: Now that I also see your edit, I want to ask out of curiosity. Why do you need to accomplish this? 

Also as for a simpler way to do it, I see no problem with 2 lines. Two lines is not repetitive. You could follow the advice given by the people below and use a macro but a macro only for 2 lines as Hogan says creates more confusion than it's worth.

Comment: @update: is nothing wrong with it **as long as the arrays don't go out of scope before the struct**. (which is correct here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare an array and assign it to an existing pointer in a single declaration. However, you can assign an array pointer to a *newly declared* pointer, like this:

```
int arr[n], *ptr = arr;
```

If you insist on staying within a single line, you could use an ugly macro, like this:

```
#define DECL_ASSIGN_INT_ARRAY(name,size,pointer) int name[(size)]; pointer = name;
```

The clarity of this one-liner is far lower than that of a two-line version from your post, so I would keep your initial version.

**EDIT** (in response to the edit of the question)

Another option is to create an unused pointer variable in a declaration, and assign your pointer in an initializer, like this:

```
void func(void) {
    struct foo f;
    int n = ...;
    int tempArr1[n], *tempPtr1 = f.a = tempArr1;
    short tempArr2[n], *tempPtr2 = f.b = tempArr2;
    char tempArr3[n], *tempPtr3 = f.c = tempArr3;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a clear case where you're in need of some refactoring. Take the similar statements, [extract them into a new function](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) (by passing a reference to the struct and the data you want the struct fields to point to) and give this new function a meaningful name.

This is probably more maintainable and readable than some fancy pointer arithmetic shortcut that you'll forget about in a few weeks or months.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `ptr` and `arr` in you example is you can change `ptr`'s value. So I guess you want to move `ptr` through the array.

So how about this:

```
int arr[n], id=0;
```

And you change the value of `id` and use `arr+id` as `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way to do this is to use a macro.  Something like (untested)

```
 #define autoptr(name,size) int Arrayname[size]; name = Arrayname;
```

I'm not clear why this is helping I think it might "look ugly" but will be easier to maintain without the macro.  In general, hiding what you are actually doing is a bad thing.